# An php if-statement with three '||' an '&&' and then an '||'?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm using the following if statement to add a class to the list item:

```
<?php
     global $post;
     $the_post_parent = $post->post_parent;
     $the_post_ID = $post->ID;
     $bbp_forums = get_posts('post_type=forum&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1&order=ASC');
?>

<li <?php if ( $post->ID == $the_post_ID || $post->ID == $the_post_parent ) echo 'class="current"'; ?>>
```

In this case, if the global post id matches the current post id the class `.current` is echoed.

I want to add three more conditions to the statement:

Excute the echo only if the current **post type** is a forum **or** topic **or** topic tag:

```
'forum' == get_post_type() 
'topic' == get_post_type() 
'topic-tag' == get_post_type()
```

So at this end if should read:

If the ...

**current post type** is a **forum** OR **topic** OR **topic tag** AND its

**global post id** is equal to the **current post id**

OR the **global post id**
 is equal to the **current post parent**

echo the class.

How that if-statement would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that : `if ( in_array(get_post_type(), array('forum', 'topic', 'topic-tag') && in_array($post->ID, array($the_post_ID,$the_post_parent) )`

Comment: Why using `in_array` for one condition but not the other ? Doesn't `if(in_array(get_post_type(), array('forum', 'topic', 'topic-tag') && in_array($post->ID, array($the_post_ID,$the_post_parent))` have more consistency ?

Comment: I like this because it makes it easier to read what post types are covered - forum, topic, etc. Also you only have to call get_post_type once as opposed to multiple times.

Comment: Nice, Shikiryu. I like your version.

Comment: I changed my answer according to @Shikiryu comment, that mike more sense. I just tried to avoid one more function call and just have logic.

Answer (score 1):

It would look exactly as you described it:

```
if ((get_post_type() == 'forum' || get_post_type() == 'topic' ...) &&
    (id == whatever || id == somethingelse))
      echo "whatever"
```

Just make sure that the parenthesis give you the precedence you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( in_array( ( $filter, array('forum','topic','topic-tag') && $global_post_id == $current_post_id ) || ( $global_post_id == $current_post_id ) )
```

You could pull the array from a model or cfg, etc.

Comment: +1, you should not mix `||` and `&&` in the if statement. although what matters is the boolean value for the if to execute.

Answer (score 0):

It would be as you read it..

```
((current post type is a forum OR topic OR topic tag )
AND
(its global post id is equal to the current post id))
OR
(the global post id is equal to the current post parent)
```